# Centering Content When Justified Left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a wrapper `<main>` and a few items inside the wrapper `<div class="item>`. The items have a width of 200px and height of 300px. I want the items to be left aligned so they stack left when the screen gets smaller. But after they wrap I want the items to center themselves.

Here's an image of the items.
[image: Items Overview]

When they wrap they look like this:
[image: Wrapped Items left justified but not centered]

But I want them to look like this
[image: Wrapped Items and Centered]

But I don't want to use `text-align: center` because then I get this formatting
[image: Center Justified and Centered]

Here is a codepen with the same code:
https://codepen.io/isaacweaver/pen/wQvBXY/

Comment: Add the code that you have so far.

Comment: Thanks, I added a codepen with the same code minus the header. And here it is as well: https://codepen.io/isaacweaver/pen/wQvBXY/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use set widths for your cards you should be able to use media queries to set your `<main>` element's width. This will snap cards to the next row (left aligned) when shrinking the browser window. No `text-align: center;` needed. I've added a snippet below that hopefully shows what you're after :)

```css
body{
  background-color: #eee;
}

main{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.item{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.item:hover{
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}

@media (min-width: 605px) {
  main {
    width: 605px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 910px) {
  main {
    width: 910px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1517px) {
  main {
    width: 1517px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </main> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, but there isn't a great and reliable way to do this with just pure html and css. The best way to do it would be to use flexbox, but you'd also need to add in empty divs when the browser window was at certain sizes to ensure that it looks right. This would be done using javascript, some math, and the browser window width.